# More efficient way of paginating in Django

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination in a django project.

I looked at [default django paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/) and found this example:

```
def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        contacts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of    results.
        contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('list.html', {"contacts": contacts})
```

It looks like it gets ALL the objects from the database and return the needed ones to the template.

That is not very efficient right?

I also looked at [django-endless-pagination](https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/) which seemed really difficult to customize.

I am looking for easily customizable solution as I will integrate it with `haystack` and `elasticsearch`

What else can I use?

Comment: Paginator doesn't get all objects https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/paginator.py#L55

Comment: @f43d65, oh of course! please write it as answer so I can accept it. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paginator won't get all the objects. As in your case, you asked for 25 objects. Thus, each page will contain 25 objects. When you try to access the next page, a new DB request will be sent to access objects 26-50.